# not able to understand getInputStream() of URLConnection

Tags: java, android, url, networking

Below is the code of getInputStream() defined in URLConnection

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new UnknownServiceException("Does not support writing to the input stream");
    }
```

I'm using this to get an inputstream object in my code

```
private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
            String jsonResponse = "";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.connect();
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: Handle the exception
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }
```

> inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

How does this statement work because in its definition it is throwing a UnknownServiceException()

Comment: The base class `URLConnection` throws an exception, but you have an `HttpURLConnection` which won't.

Comment: But this method is not overriden within HttpURLConnection

Comment: `"Does not support writing to the input stream");` ?? One does not write to an input stream. Impossible. You can only read from an input stream. Wrong message.

Comment: @RobyJacob No, but the connection is retrieved from the `URL` which delegates to an `URLStreamHandler`, in this case I suspect `sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler`, which may very well create yet another subclass. Step through with a debugger if you really need to know the implementation details.